# upgrading Windows Azure Service Bus from 1.x to 2.0 - Retry Policy

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am going through an effort to upgrade code that used the old Windows Azure Service Bus (pre 2.0).

This code based used the Enterprise Library Transient Fault Handling blocks to provide a retry policy that is leveraged when calling into the Service Bus API to send and receive queue messages.

Typically the code would look like this (minus all the try/catch/finally, etc.):

```
 retryPolicy.Execute(() =>  { queueClient.Send(msg); });
```

However, in Service Bus 2.0, retry policy is built into the messaging factory, so I can set:

```
_msgFactory.RetryPolicy = RetryExponential.Default;
var queueClient = _msgFactory.CreateQueueClient(path, mode);
```

Once that is done, I can remove the TFH retry policy's Execute() wrapper around the call to `queueClient.Send(msg).`

Is this really all that is needed to ensure the queue client is retrying on transient exceptions?  Seems to simple.  How can I prove that it is retrying?

Comment: that is indeed all you need to do ;)
it's not easy to simulate errors that will be handled transient.  maybe a very short network issue (although I'm not sure that client side connection issues will be seen as transient)

Comment: @SamVanhoutte Thanks! If you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is indeed all you need to do ;) it's not easy to simulate errors that will be handled transient. maybe a very short network issue (although I'm not sure that client side connection issues will be seen as transient)