# Azure Service Bus: transient errors (exceptions) received through the message pump with built-in retry policy. Why?

Tags: azure, queue, message-queue, azureservicebus, retrypolicy

I've been reading on the [Event-Driven Message Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn198643.aspx) introduced in April 2013, the [OnMessageOptions.ExceptionReceived Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.onmessageoptions.exceptionreceived.aspx), the built-in [RetryPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.retrypolicy.aspx) (May 2013, RetryPolicy.Default), [The Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934(v=pandp.50).aspx) (2011) which is outdated, and more (see bottom).

I've been monitoring the exceptions received through the message pump for transient errors and I get daily **MessagingCommunicationExceptions**. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh851746.aspx) (Updated: September 16, 2014), recommend the following :

> This exception signals a communication error that can manifest itself
>   when a connection from the messaging client to the Service Bus
>   infrastructure cannot be successfully established. In most cases,
>   provided network connectivity exists, this error can be treated as
>   transient. The client can attempt to retry the operation that has
>   resulted in this type of exception. It is also recommended that you
>   verify whether the domain name resolution service (DNS) is operational
>   as this error may indicate that the target host name cannot be
>   resolved.

My understanding is that there is no extra code to write to handle transients errors on the Service Bus after version 2.1 (2013). Unless my premise is wrong, why am I receiving transients errors each and every day? Should exceptions received through the message pump be ignored? If ignored, I can only assume that unexpected exceptions will also be ignored.. and I don't want that to happen of course.

*Version of Microsoft.ServiceBus is 2.4.0.0*

Also of interest : [upgrading Windows Azure Service Bus from 1.x to 2.0 - Retry Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768943/upgrading-windows-azure-service-bus-from-1-x-to-2-0-retry-policy), [Introducing the Event-Driven Message Programming Model for the Windows Azure Service Bus](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/introducing-the-event-driven-message-programming-model-for-the-windows-azure-service-bus/), [What's New in the Azure SDK 2.0 Release (April 2013)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn198643.aspx), [What's New in the Service Bus 2.1 Release (May 2013)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn275924.aspx), [Transient Fault Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675232.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Officially answered [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/cf60ace8-5376-43dc-af0c-c601761a7585/daily-transient-errors-received-through-the-message-pump-with-builtin-retry-policy-why?forum=servbus). In short, **exceptions are bubbled for monitoring purpose** after retry attempts. In long:

> The transient exceptions you get from ExceptionHandler callback means
>   those exceptions are bubled up after retry attempts. You should just
>   log it for monitoring purposes. Take action if you need to. For
>   eample, if your client loses network connectivity you should expect
>   large number of communication exceptions bleeding through the handler.
>   In such cases you may need to take proper actions to fix things. So
>   the answer to question "should I ignore them?" really depends on
>   conditions. - Serkant Karaca, Microsoft