# Azure Service Bus MessagingException

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm using the Azure Service Bus and everything works fine. But when I'm checking the logs for the consumer of the messages of the bus I can find a lot of *MessagingExceptions* or *MessagingCommunicationException*. Anyone know how to solve those errors?

**MessagingCommunicationException:**

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException: Error during communication with Service Bus. Check the connection information, then retry. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: Internal Server Error: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a premature session shutdown. TrackingId: TRACKING_ID, Timestamp:4/20/2015 8:10:58 AM

Server stack trace: 

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.DuplexCorrelationAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass17.<GetAsyncSteps>b__a(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [2]: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [3]: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand(IAsyncResult result, IEnumerable`1& messages)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult.TryReceiveEnd(IAsyncResult r, IEnumerable`1& messages)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, IEnumerable`1& messages)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceivePump.PumpAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__1b(PumpAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

**MessagingExceptions:**

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingException: The server was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. If the problem persists, please contact your Service Bus administrator and provide the tracking id. TrackingId:TRACKING_ID, Timestamp:4/20/2015 6:42:00 AM ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: The server was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. If the problem persists, please contact your Service Bus administrator and provide the tracking id. TrackingId:TRACKING_ID, Timestamp:4/20/2015 6:42:00 AM

Server stack trace: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.ThrowIfFaultMessage(Message wcfMessage)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.HandleMessageReceived(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.DuplexCorrelationAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass17.<GetAsyncSteps>b__a(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [2]: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [3]: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand(IAsyncResult result, IEnumerable`1& messages)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand(IAsyncResult result, IEnumerable`1& messages)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnEndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, IEnumerable`1& messages)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__72(RetryReceiveAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult.TryReceiveEnd(IAsyncResult r, IEnumerable`1& messages)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, IEnumerable`1& messages)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceivePump.PumpAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__1b(PumpAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take action on messaging exceptions. They are transient errors and are logged for monitoring purposes.

[Azure Service Bus: transient errors (exceptions) received through the message pump with built-in retry policy. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875625/azure-service-bus-transient-errors-exceptions-received-through-the-message-pu?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have an invalid queue name. For example, we had a queue named `something/$DeadLetter` instead of the special `something/$DeadLetterQueue`. Correcting the queue name fixed the issue.